# PHP 5.4 error - Non-static method

Tags: ee2, php-errors

Moving an old EE 2.5.5 site to a server with PHP 5.4 instead of the old 5.3, I have run into this error, and can't see how to fix it:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Non-static method Comment::form() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Filename: libraries/Template.php

Line Number: 3004
```

Line 3004 is:

```
$str = str_replace($match[0][$i], Comment::form(TRUE, $this->EE->functions->cached_captcha), $str);
```

Sadly, upgrading EE is not an option at the moment.